# 301 Redirect Gatsby S3 CloudFront

Tags: amazon-s3, redirect, amazon-cloudfront

I am trying to apply 301 redirect with my Gatsby and S3 + Cloudfront , and so far i have no success ,
i have about 210 redirect url , i will list below my configuration .

```
 createRedirect({
  fromPath: `/old-url`,
  toPath: `/new-url`,
  isPermanent: true,
  redirectInBrowser: true,
});

{
resolve: 'gatsby-plugin-s3',
options: {
bucketName: process.env.S3_BUCKET,
region: 'eu-west-1',
protocol: 'https',
hostname: 'stage-mydomain.de',
bucketPrefix: 'de',
generateRoutingRules: true,
generateRedirectObjectsForPermanentRedirects: true,
 }
}
```

note that i have no plugin related to redirect inside my config ,
what i would like to accomplish is pure 301 server side redirect , i dont want JS redirect and Meta redirect because
Js will not work with JS disabled and Meta is not good for SEO .

can someone help please?
Thanks